# Does R language objects address changes whenever we try to change its value?

Tags: r

When I execute the following, address of changing whenever x value is changing.

```
library(pryr)
x <- x + 10
address(x)
tracemem(x)
x <- x + 10
address(x)
tracemem(x)
x <- x + 10
address(x)
tracemem(x)
x <- x + 10
address(x)
tracemem(x)
```

Any reason? Thanks.

Comment: Are you doing this in RStudio or Rgui?

Answer (score 1):

The [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html) book by Hadley (specifically chapter on Memory) will probably be a good resource to help explain.

In particular, the following:

> When refs(x) is 1, modification will occur in place. When refs(x) is
>   2, R will make a copy (this ensures that other pointers to the object
>   remain unaffected).

What you have encountered is a setting where `R` is "copying on modify" and creating a new reference.  As the chapter explains, there are cases where `R` will copy on modify and cases where it will modify in place.